# SQL Query - splitting data into multiple tables and joining based on a range of IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have one large data set that has the following columns and rows as an example.

```
       Latest   Name   Code    Date         Number  
         Y      abc    def     9/10/2017    123
         N      abc    def     10/10/2014   123
         N      abc    def     08/08/2008   123
```

I need to change the output so that it reads as follows:

```
      Latest   Name   Code    Date         Number  Latest   Name   Code   Number
         Y      abc    def     9/10/2017    123      N      abc    def     10/10/2014   123
         Y      abc    def     9/10/2017    123      N      abc    def     08/08/2008   123
```

I have thought through the issue and I think I need to split the table into 2 smaller tables, one with Y as Latest and one with N as Latest then use an inner join to match the results?
can anyone help me with this please?
I have tried the following:

```
      CREATE Table Latest AS
      SELECT * 
      FROM [Original Table]
      WHERE Latest = 'Y'

      CREATE Table Latest AS
      SELECT * 
      FROM [Original Table]
      WHERE Latest = 'N'
```

However I'm getting an error when I tried to run the queries - Incorrect Syntax near SELECT, expecting ID, can anyone help please?

Comment: Can you state your desired output in the form of an English business rule? In other words, what is the logic for matching a "Y" row with an "N" row? From your example its not clear what output should be if you have, say, 10 Y records and 99 N records for the same `number` or `name` value.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to add that in. N rows should match Y rows against the code column.

Comment: What is the join attribute?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `name` is a join attribute then the following query returns the expected output

```
  SELECT t1.*, t2.*
  FROM
  (
    SELECT * 
    FROM [Original Table]
    WHERE Latest = 'Y'
  ) t1
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT * 
    FROM [Original Table]
    WHERE Latest = 'N'
  ) t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
```